# JODATIME withZone displays incorrect offset

Tags: java, coldfusion, jodatime

I'm using Java objects in Coldfusion so my code is a little off.

I've got a function that looks somewhat like this:

```
function getJODAOffset(sTimezone){
    local.oDateTimeZone = createObject('java','org.joda.time.DateTimeZone');
    local.oInstant = createObject('Java','org.joda.time.Instant');

    local.oFormatter = createObject("Java",'org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat');
    local.oFormatter = local.oFormatter.forPattern('ZZ');

    local.tTime = local.oDateTimeZone.forID(arguments.sTimezone).getStandardOffset(local.oInstant); //sTimezone = 'Europe/London';

    return local.oFormatter.withZone(local.oDateTimeZone.forID(arguments.sTimezone)).print(local.tTime);

}
```

this gives me an output of "**+01:00**" when i expect "**+00:00**", and i have no idea as to why.

Comment: If you believe the problem is in Joda Time, you should be able to create a short but complete pure Java program which demonstrates the problem, right? That would make it *much* simpler to diagnose.

Comment: I know it's a pain, but my dev environment is not properly geared up for me to write Java code.  the java code should pretty much be the same though without the createObject bits.

Comment: Well that makes it very hard for the (larger) number of people who are trying to help you. I'll see whether I can come up with *either* a counterexample (i.e. suggesting that what looks like the equivalent Java code works) *or* a Java example showing the problem/

Comment: Please see my second answer - I understand everything except how you're able to call `getStandardOffset` with an `Instant` at all.

Comment: actually thats completely my fault, i was using getMillis on getStandardOffset but hadn't copied it over to my psuedoeycode.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad that mystery is solved. In future, it would be nice if you'd wait until you're in a suitable environment where you can write a short but complete program in the most appropriate language before posting the question. I'm glad we sorted it out anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I think I've got it now.

Firstly, I'm not sure how your code works at *all* - there's no `getStandardOffset(Instant)` method as far as I can see - only `getStandardOffset(long)`. We can fix that by calling `getMillis()`, but I don't know what Coldfusion is doing.

Anyway, I can reproduce the problem here:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
        Instant now = new Instant();
        long offset = zone.getStandardOffset(now.getMillis());
        System.out.println("Offset = " + offset);
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ZZ")
                                                 .withZone(zone);
        System.out.println(format.print(offset));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Offset = 0
+01:00
```

The problem is that you're passing an *offset* to `DateTimeFormatter.print`, which is expecting a "millis since the epoch" value - an *instant*. So it's treating it as equivalent to:

```
format.print(new Instant(0))
```

Now `new Instant(0)` represents midnight on January 1st 1970 UTC - but [the Europe/London time zone was genuinely at +01:00 at that point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_Kingdom#Experimentations_with_Central_European_Time)... and that's the offset you're seeing. So it's not a bug in Joda Time - it's a bug in how you're using it.

One option is to instead create a `DateTimeZone` which is *fixed* at the offset you've found, and format *any* instant using that zone:

```
DateTimeZone fixedZone = DateTimeZone.forOffsetMillis(offset);
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ZZ")
                                         .withZone(fixedZone);
System.out.println(format.print(0L)); // Value won't affect offset
```